# .htaccess redirect .com.ar domain to .com

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain mudomain.com.ar and want to redirect all incoming traffic to mudomain.com

I've tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mudomain.com.ar$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mudomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This rule redirects all traffic correctly. For example:

mudomain.com.ar/hello/ to mudomain.com/hello/

All traffic except traffic incoming to mudomain.com.ar/ar/

It seems like the .ar/ar/ in the domain is preventing the regex to work, but I can't understand why. Ideas?

Edit:

/ar/ contains the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the webroot directory contains the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does `/ar/` contain another .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava It does! The code inside that .htaccess is:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use DNS for the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache 2.4 then add this line after `RewriteEngine On` line in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

[Read more about `RewriteOptions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions)